# Is it possible to hide an area of hard disk from root user?

Tags: linux, kernel, security, root

Do linux kernel have a feature that can be used to hide an area of hard disk (e.g last 1GB of hard disk) from root user or at least make that area completely unwritable by any means?

Comment: Who - if not root - should introduce that feature? That "user" could circumvent it as well...

Comment: Depending on what the _puprose_ is, one could possibly do it (whatever it is) by other means.

Comment: Unreadable stored data at rest, yes (encrypted filesystem using an external key, such as a Yubikey)... unwritable, no, not normally.  However, once the user decrypts the filesystem, then root can access the data as well.

Comment: @RudiC The kernel programmer and one which configures it has more power than root user. perhaps you misunderstand my question or my wording is ambiguous.

Comment: @gopy Do you want to protect it from root only during runtime, or during early boot as well? Do you want to protect it from the root user on _another_ computer that has the hard drive plugged into it?

Answer (score 3):

The ATA specification has something called Host Protected Area.

This means that the capacity of the device is artificially made less than the full capacity. The area above the reported maximum LBA is this Host Protected Area, and can only be accessed after sending a special command to unlock this area.

This is typically used for storing recovery data, so that the user can't accidentally repartition the disk and wipe out the recovery partition; it's not a partition, after all. My IBM Thinkpad from 2004 implemented this, and it worked quite well.

This may be useful for your application.

Comment: [hdparam + root = HPA compromised](https://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/DCO_and_HPA)

Comment: @RubberStamp Unless you use mandatory access controls to restrict root.

Comment: @forest ... by definition, the root user can change everything. You'll need to give a tested and repeatable example rather than an unqualified declarative statement.

Comment: @RubberStamp That is incorrect. The root user runs in ring 3 as a regular user, and only has powers via POSIX capabilities. In other words, it only has powers by default because the kernel (which runs in ring 0) trusts it. It can be easily restricted with mandatory access controls which disable this trust. This is common on secure server configurations. Please look into how SELinux works, for example. Or look for any of the numerous examples on [security.se].

Comment: @forest ... you need to give a clear, tested, and repeatable example.  The root user has access everything, including the SELinux settings.  There's no way to hide the settings file... which can simply be overwritten if need be by the root user, regardless of any and all permissions... and, no, pointing to another StackExchange is not a clear, tested, and repeatable example.

Comment: @RubberStamp Please visit [The DMZ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) so we do not clutter this up. I am happy to explain there.

Comment: @forest ... perhaps another time... in meantime, if you'd like to answer this question with a clear, tested, and repeatable answer, it would much appreciated...

Comment: @RubberStamp Alright. Please configure AppArmor to disallow write access to block devices in `/dev` as well as `/boot` and run bash or a similar shell under said profile. Run hdparm and see that you will be unable to issue the IOCTLs necessary to change the HPA. You can further enable the "[lockdown](https://lwn.net/Articles/750730/)" functionality in certain newer kernels to disable access to module insertion, ioperm and iopl, sensitive MSRs, ACPI custom_method, ACPI AML insertion, kprobes, and debugfs.

Comment: This is possible because the kernel, which runs in ring 0 (supervisor mode) and has power to everything, by default will trust root (which differentiates itself from any other user simply by having `cred->uid` at 0. This allows various checks in the kernel to be made that permit syscalls for root processes that would otherwise be denied, for example the IOCTLs on the file descriptor necessary to modify the HPA. However, LSMs hook these checks, much like DAC, and can be used to prevent even the root user from performing said syscalls.

Comment: @forest >Please configure AppArmor ... how does one do that?  Which system user does this configuring?  And which system user does the "unconfiguring" ... and who turns off SELinux in `/etc/selinux/config` ? ... Oh, that would be root.

Comment: @RubberStamp You are assuming that root cannot "give up" its powers by configuring SELinux to prevent it from accessing the SELinux configuration. On an architectural level, root runs in ring 3, which means it will trigger a GPF if it tries to access memory that is not part of its virtual address space. Compare this to the kernel, in ring 0, where almost anything can be done. This is why syscalls exist even for the root user. Syscalls allow the root user, which, from the perspective of the CPU, is just as unprivileged as any other user. The kernel simply allows UID 0 to bypass certain checks.

Comment: That's what makes booting in single user mode so delicious... however, I will refain from continuing down the rabbit hole... present the case and the evidence and post it as an answer and help make StackExchange a better place to find clear, well reasoned, and repeatable answers.

Comment: @RubberStamp A local root user cannot initiate single user mode, only a physical user can. Are you confusing privileged local attacks with privileged physical attacks? If so, then your initial comment should be changed to "hdparm + physical access = HPA compromised", which would be true.

Comment: @RubberStamp Do you want me to actually write a program that utilizes e.g. seccomp sandboxing so that it can run as root while being unable to do any harm? Or link you to a container?

Comment: @forest ... any local user can simply change the files at will by booting the system from a live USB system, mount the root filesystem and modify any and all settings.... **END free discussion**

Comment: @RubberStamp "Local" in information security does not mean physical. A local root user cannot boot from a live USB system because it has no hands to hold a USB stick. I can give you a root shell to my server where the process cannot do anything harmful. Do you think you could boot from a live USB then?

Comment: @RubberStamp Additionally, please understand that, just because physical access (usually) equals root access does not mean the inverse is true. Root access does not necessarily imply physical access.

Answer (score 1):

No, the root user is always able to write to a block device, unless the controller of the block device determines that an area is read-only. 
Example: when you flip the read-only switch on an SD card, the SD card controller doesn't allow writing.
There's flash memory devices with read-only partitions e.g. in your phone or TV to contain decoder keys.

For consumer hard disks you'd have to modify the firmware, otherwise root can access every byte.

Comment: Can a controller make a particular block read only or it  can make only full device read only?

Comment: The controller is a microchip on the storage device. E.g. the controller on an SSD keeps track of broken sectors and usually prevents you from writing to them, and those sectors may not even be visible to the host device.

Comment: How about writing a new driver for the hard disk and forcing user space programs to use this driver? (I don't know how)

Comment: You could make a device (e.g. a consumer NAS) and supply it with an OS with a custom driver that limits writing to part of a block device. However a root user can unload that kernel module and load his own OS or kernel modules as he likes.

Comment: @StefaanGhysels You can set `kernel.modules_disabled=1` to avoid that.